# Monaco editor Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^*-+:*$/: Nothing to repeat

Tags: javascript, frontend, monaco-editor

I'm using Monaco editor in my app. I get this error on Firefox and some versions of Chrome and somehow it works fine with version 96 of Chrome

Console displays:

Invalid regular expression: `/^*-+:*$/: Nothing to repeat`

[image: Error in console]

This is the code:

```
    $(function () {
        require.config({ paths: { vs: '/static/node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' } });
        let editor;
        require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], () => {
            editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById("content"), {
                theme: 'vs-dark',
                language: "yaml",
                model: monaco.editor.createModel(`{{content | safe }}`),
                wordWrap: 'on',
                automaticLayout: true,
                minimap: {
                    enabled: false
                },
                scrollbar: {
                    useShadows: false,
                    verticalHasArrows: true,
                    horizontalHasArrows: true,
                    vertical: 'auto',
                    horizontal: 'auto',
                    verticalScrollbarSize: 17,
                    horizontalScrollbarSize: 17,
                    arrowSize: 30
                }
            });
        });
```

Comment: I believe the problem is with `^*` as it doesn't make sense to specify "zero or more beginning of sequence".

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the first `*` or the starting `^`.  You cannot repeat the starting `^`.  Choose to use one literal or the other. So 'zero or more `^`' or starting with `*`.

```js
/\^*/
```

or

```js
/^\*/
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply guys. Turns out it's a problem with flask minify, removing spaces before the '*' in the regex mentioned above.